# How do I make Bootstrap grids work as expected inside a tab pane?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I've seen a few questions similar to this, but not hitting the exact same problem that I have seen.

I already know how to make grids (more or less) work inside a tab pane. However, they don't seem to be working as I expect. What I expect is to see is a set of tabs, each using their own personal space to display grid-contained data. What I see, instead, is sets of tabs with data that is attempting to share the same grid space, and therefore the rows of data are stacking so that they are pushed down the page. The entire tab area will be twice as high as necessary, with the data on Tab2 being located on the bottom half of the tab pane, while the top half is empty (or would be holding data from Tab1).

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">

      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
             ...tab1, col1 information...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
             ...tab1, col2 information...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
             ...tab2, col1 information...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
             ...tab2, col2 information...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is if I'm coding something wrong or if Bootstrap simply does not support what I'm trying to accomplish. I have already tested the idea of removing the .row divs, with no success. (The data stacks unevenly, rather than staying in separate rows.) It appears as if .col*-* classes are unable to share the same space, even while hidden.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ha ha. The second `active` is a straight up typo on my example. Can't believe I completely missed that I was using `id="tab-content"` and not `class="tab-content"`. Must have been a long day. Thank you very much, everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing `.tab-content` class on the container with tabs, which applies `display:none` to the hidden ones. Also, both of your tabs have `active` class, which makes both of them to show up at the beginning.

Here is the markup:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">

      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              ...tab1, col1 information...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              ...tab1, col2 information...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              ...tab2, col1 information...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              ...tab2, col2 information...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: None of this solutions are working for me. All cols are among each other...is that a browser update issue?? Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181

Comment: @Rawburner check the example in the Full page mode, I'm running the same version of Chrome and they should work fine. The columns in my example are displayed as rows because they are using `sm` breakpoint from Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Working example

```css
#tabby h3 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.colorBlue {
  color: white;
  background-color: #266080;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
}
.colorRed {
  color: white;
  background-color: #f00;
  padding: 15px;
}
.colorYellow {
  color: white;
  background-color: #E4EC45;
  padding: 15px;
}
.colorGrey {
  color: white;
  background-color: #343537;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Panels and Grids</h2>

</div>
<div id="tabby" class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"> <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Uno</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Dos</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Tres</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
      <h3>Tab One</h3>

      <div class="col-md-6 colorBlue">This is my first 6.</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 colorRed">This is my second 6.</div>
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
      <h3>Tab Two</h3>

      <div class="col-md-4 colorBlue">This is my first 3.</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 colorRed">This is my second 3.</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 colorYellow">This is my second 3.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3">
      <h3>Tab Three</h3>

      <div class="col-md-3 colorBlue">This is my first 4.</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 colorRed">This is my second 4.</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 colorYellow">This is my second 4.</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 colorGrey">This is my second 4.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**AJK**, This will keep the **Tab2** content to the top and not move down the page. You had `tab-content` as a `id` when you just needed it as a `class`.
Also if you do not want the divs with the text to stack like I show here use col-xs-xx.

[image: bootstrap tabs]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>HTML/CSS Block not appearing</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.spacer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}    
.block {
  height: 240px;
  padding-top: 15px;  
  background-color:orangered;  
}  
.tab2-clr {
  color: blue; 
}
       
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container col-lg-12 spacer"></div>
    
<div class="container block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">    
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a  href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            
            <div class="tab-content ">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <h4>...tab1, col1 information...</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <h4>...tab1, col2 information...</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade in tab2-clr" id="tab2">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <h4>...tab2, col1 information...</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <h4>...tab2, col2 information...</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    
    

    

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

### I have this issues too. i experimenting by using accepted answer then here the solution i got

add row class in your tab content 
such as this :

```
<div class="tab-content"> 
    <div class="row"> 
       <!-- Write your grid column in here -->


    </div>

</div>
```